# Improve this generic abstract class

Tags: c#, generics, oop, interface

I have the following abstract class design, I was wondering if anyone can suggest any improvements in terms of stronger enforcement of our requirements or simplifying implementing of the ControllerBase.

```
//Dependency Provider base
public abstract class ControllerBase<TContract, TType> where TType : TContract, class
{
    public static TContract Instance 
    {
        get { 
    return ComponentFactory.GetComponent<TContract, TType>(); 
            }
    }

 public TContract GetComponent<TContract, TType>() where TType : TContract, class
 {   
        component = (TType)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TType), true);
        RegisterComponentInstance<TContract>(component);
 }
}

//Contract
public interface IController
{
 void DoThing();
}

//Actual Class Logic
public class Controller: ControllerBase<IController,Controller>
{
 public void DoThing();

    //internal constructor
    internal Controller(){}

}


//Usage
public static void Main()
{
 Controller.Instance.DoThing();
}
```

The following facts should always be true,

- `TType` should always implement `TContract` (Enforced using a generic constraint)
- `TContract` must be an interface (Can't find a way to enforce it)
- `TType` shouldn't have public constructor, just an internal one, is there any way to Enforce that using `ControllerBase`?
- `TType` must be an concrete class (Didn't include New() as a generic constrain since the constructors should be marked as Internal)

Comment: Enforcing TContract being an interface seems like a nonsense. Do not get me wrong, but interfaces can not be instantiated. Understand them as mere contracts, nothing more, they enforce (mostly) only behaviour. But they are not types, nor classes. You should try to explain why you want it to be interface.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I said interface, I meant abstract class

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on why it wouldn't work?

Comment: we have been using it for quite a bit, I'm just looking for a way to improve it.

Comment: if you are talking about GetComponent then it might be the case, it actually is in another class, I just put it there to simplify the question.

Comment: Hmmm, I tried to stub out the code, but Controller.Instance was not compiling for me.  I'll have to look at that again.

Comment: My apologies, I just tried it again and I made a mistake in my earlier testing.  Very interesting; I didn't realize a generic static member would inherit like that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to enforce TType being a concrete class and forbidding constructor success at the same time. I guess it might be possible to try to instantiate TType, which will succeed only if it is a concrete type, however, you want to avoid instantiation. I would suggest trying to throw an exception from the constructor. In your controller base, you can surround the instantiation with exception handling code. This will get through compile time only if you instantiate concrete type and it will get through runtime if you throw an exception... This is overall bad practice (if possible) and I guess you need totally different design to achive what are you looking for.